# Django only want to get first row of a queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, django-admin, django-orm

i want to display the first entry of a queryset.
i try some answers here but it does´tn work on my code example.

here is my code:

```
class FeatureFilmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        QuoteAndEffortSetInLine,
        ProjectCompanySetInLine,
        VendorVFXSetInLine,
        VendorSetInLine,
        StaffListSetInLine,
]
list_display = ["title", "program_length", "get_production_company_name"]

def get_production_company_name(self, Featurefilm):
    return FeatureFilm.objects.filter(pk=Featurefilm.id).values(
        "projectcompanyset__production_company__name"
    )
```

so i actually want to display the production_company, from the first table of ProjectCompanySet in the admin as list_display.
so i actually want to display the production_company, from the first table of ProjectCompanySet in the admin as list_display. but with the code above, it will show me all production_company, if there are multiple ProjectcompanySet. What is displayed so far is also not the production_company name but the **str** function and not the data field itself. Here I would need help please.

here are the models of my problem:

```
  class CompanyOrBranch(CompanyBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
    "Firma oder Niederlassung",
    max_length=60,
    blank=False,
    ) 


class FeatureFilm(ProjectBaseModel):
    class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Kinofilm"
    verbose_name_plural = "Kinofilme"

class ProjectCompanySet(models.Model):
    feature = models.ForeignKey(
        FeatureFilm,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
)
    production_company = models.ForeignKey(
        CompanyOrBranch,
        related_name="production_company",
        verbose_name="Produktionsfirma",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
)
```

here is the output of my admin list:
[image]

Comment: you can probably juste add [:1] to get only the first element : `return FeatureFilm.objects.filter(pk=Featurefilm.id).values(
        "projectcompanyset__production_company__name"
    )[:1]`

Comment: thank you, that was the solution, but i get now the first row and only the first row: <QuerySet [{'projectcompanyset__production_company__name': 'Die Produktionsfirma#1'}]> but how i get the clean string now of the production_company name ?

Comment: use `values_list` with `flat=True` instead of `values`